# get form values from jquery dialog iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe

I have tried to scale this code down to the basics

I have this jquery dialog. It has an iframe that is a populated JSP with a form
When the user clicks the save button, i want to grab some of the form values from the iframe form.
I am just not sure how to access those form fields(title,htmldata are the form field names) from the the Save function.

```
$("#dialog-edit-raw").dialog({
    autoOpen: false, height: 300, width: 500,  position: [200, 100], modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Save: function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/servlet/trainingServlet",
                        data: ({method: 'ajaxSaveArticle',title: title_from_Form }),
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        beforeSend: function(){
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        },
                        success: function(data){
                        }
                    });

                },
                Close: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: function() {
                $( this ).html('');
            }
    });
```

---

```
$( ".ui-state-default" ).live("click", function(event){
     $("#dialog-edit-raw")
      .html('<iframe id="iframeedit" style="border: 0px;" src="/servlet/myServlet?method=editDoc&ID='+tID+'&raw=1" width="100%" height="580" "></iframe>')
.dialog('open');
});
```

The form looks like has two inputs:

```
input name="title" id="title" size="50" value="" type="text"
textarea cols="50" id="htmldata" name="htmldata" rows="6"
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I found it:

```
$("#iframeedit").contents().find("#title");
```